# Can phonegap build, run the app without android sdk?

Tags: cordova

I'm new to phonegap, I tried to make a simple phonegap android app with facebook login plugin

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

I use phonegap cli to create an app. And add that facebook plugin into app. Now how to test the phonegap app? Do I need download android sdk?

Comment: What did phone gap actually "create" if you don't have the Android SDK?

Comment: it create bulk of html, js and css files

Comment: Which isn't anywhere close to a complete Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the Android SDK. Otherwise Cordova can't build against its SDK. Cordova will tell you how to install the right version of the SDK (there are dozens upon dozens of versions) when you try to add the android platform:

> `cordova platform add android`